# File validation in python, the better approach and why

Tags: regex, python-2.7, validation, string-literals

I am working on a project for work that involves the parsing of a file for insertion into our local database. In an effort to write efficient robust code I am trying to see what the best approach is for validating the file. I have written two python scripts:

```
EXPECTED = 'PubNo|Name|CoverID|Issue|CustomLabel|Split'

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

test = lines[0].replace(" ", "").strip()

if test[-1] == '|' or test[0] == '|':
    test = test.strip('|')

if test.lower() == EXPECTED.lower():
    print 'Successful Match!'
else:
    print 'Bad match :('
```

and

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

patt = re.compile(r"\|?PubNo\|Name\|CoverID\|Issue\|CustomLabel\|Split\|?", re.I)

test = re.sub(r"\s", "", lines[0])
m = re.match(patt, test)

if m.group():
    print 'Successful Match!'
else:
    print 'Bad match :('
```

As I hope is obvious, I am using simple string literal comparisons with various formatting done to ensure *some* safety, as well as a version that relies purely on regex's. Could anyone explain the pros and cons of these two approaches? They both take the same amount of time to execute and are both fairly readable. The only advantage I can see so far is that using regex's means not having to do so much manual formatting prior to comparing string literals.

Comment: For starters - why are you reading the whole file only to 'validate' its first line?

Comment: because after validation, assuming it is valid, the file will be read in. that isn't where my concern is, the proper efficient way would of course be to read the first line, validate, then read the rest in. I am only interested in the pros/cons of validating the line itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't see a problem of loading the whole file, and assuming you fix your regex (the way you presented it the program would break on non-match, you should check if there was a match, not if there is a group within it) those two are **not the same**. Consider the first line of your file being:

```
PubNo | Name | CoverID | Issue | CustomLabel | Split | SomethingMore
```

Your regex 'validator' will mark it successful, your string compare won't. If you want your first column 'validator' to match precisely that string and nothing else, you have to change your regex pattern to `r"\|?PubNo\|Name\|CoverID\|Issue\|CustomLabel\|Split\|?$"`. Also, your regex 'validator' will consume all the whitespace characters in the 'replacement' part including tabs, which your string comparator won't.

All things being equal - string search will be **considerably** faster in both cases - and that is not counting loading of the regex engine, preparing the patterns and all other supporting structures needed. Even if you cache the pattern, and remove all of the disadvantages of regex, string compare will still be faster. Consider a setup like:

```
import re

VALID = "PubNo|Name|CoverID|Issue|CustomLabel|Split"

# prepare the regex patterns
PATTERN_VALID = re.compile(r"\|?{}\|?".format(VALID.replace("|", r"\|")))
PATTERN_STRICT = re.compile(PATTERN_VALID.pattern + "$", re.I)
CLEAR_WHITESPACE = re.compile(r"\s")

# let's not disadvantage the string compare, too
VALID_LOWER = VALID.lower()

def string_valid(data):
    if data.strip("| ").replace(" ", "").lower().startswith(VALID_LOWER):
        return True
    return False

def string_valid_strict(data):
    if data.strip("| \r\n").replace(" ", "").lower() == VALID_LOWER:
        return True
    return False

def regexp_valid(data):
    if PATTERN_VALID.match(CLEAR_WHITESPACE.sub("", data)):
        return True
    return False

def regexp_valid_strict(data):
    if PATTERN_STRICT.match(CLEAR_WHITESPACE.sub("", data)):
        return True
    return False
```

This would cover both cases (strict and matching the beginning only) with both approaches. You weren't considering building your regex pattern to ignore whitespace so you wouldn't need substitution, but it wouldn't speed it up considerably (actually, it will probably run slower than this).

So now if you have 3 files, say `good.txt`, `strict.txt` and `bad.txt` that cover all three cases, you can run an ad-hoc test like this:

```
# open test files and only get the first lines
with open("good.txt", "r") as g, open("strict.txt", "r") as s, open("bad.txt", "r") as b:
    g = g.readline()  # overwrite is perfectly fine for our test
    s = s.readline()  # overwrite is perfectly fine for our test
    b = b.readline()  # overwrite is perfectly fine for our test

# make sure our functions perform adequately
assert string_valid(g) is regexp_valid(g) is True
assert string_valid_strict(g) is regexp_valid_strict(g) is False
assert string_valid(s) is regexp_valid(s) is True
assert string_valid_strict(s) is regexp_valid_strict(s) is True
assert string_valid(b) is regexp_valid(b) is False
assert string_valid_strict(b) is regexp_valid_strict(b) is False
```

And if you time the calls for each of those (so 3 calls, with 3 different lines per loop) over, say, 100,000 loops you get:

```
Python 2.7.11

string_valid:        100,000 loops: 0.31 s, per loop:  3.15 µs
string_valid_strict: 100,000 loops: 0.27 s, per loop:  2.76 µs
regexp_valid:        100,000 loops: 1.34 s, per loop: 13.44 µs
regexp_valid_strict: 100,000 loops: 1.38 s, per loop: 13.83 µs

==

Python 3.5.1

string_valid:        100,000 loops: 0.37 s, per loop:  3.73 µs
string_valid_strict: 100,000 loops: 0.33 s, per loop:  3.37 µs
regexp_valid:        100,000 loops: 1.13 s, per loop: 11.28 µs
regexp_valid_strict: 100,000 loops: 1.22 s, per loop: 12.17 µs
```

And this is the best case scenario for regex - we're even compiling the whitespace removing pattern. OTOH, string search can be optimized even more (slicing instead of `startswith()` for the non-strict example, etc.).

Regular expressions are great, but only when needed. There is no reason to utilize regex to solve simple problems like this one.